# how to render UIView over UIImageView in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

I am looking for a way to render UIView over UIImageView on camera in swift. My problem is to capture only small rectangular portion of image.for this i tried by reducing the size of my UIImageView but in this case camera adjusted whole image in this small area which is not my objective.

Finally i decided to hide camera by rendering some other component over it from both side up/down, how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0)
view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: here in your solution i m getting UIImage but when i am setting it into my UIImageView (in which I m running my camera) camera frame become invisible .when i am rendering it over camera frame  frame changing become very slow 1 frame /sec .Is there any way to render it over ?